# Vue beforeUpdate event firing twice for recursive component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Just started learning vue js and have been experimenting with a **recursive tree example** based on this example the offical example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/pnqzspoe)

The example above starts out with treedata having a **single root** followed by many children, I was trying to ***extend the same to having multiple root elements,*** example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mckd6fpq/).

In my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mckd6fpq/), I notice the `beforeUpdate` is being called twice for every component click, moreover even if I try to directly push elements into `children`, the `beforeUpdate` is still called twice whereas in the official recursive example, this happens once(debugged via vue-devtools). I'm unable to find a explanation for the above behaviour, can anyone advice on why this happens?

Is this because I do a `v-for` in `li` instead of the actual component name?

**EDIT:**
I add a `datetime` to see which all elements are being rendered & it appears in my example, all children to be re-rendered, seen via the time on the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Steven Spungin who helped me track the id's of the components that helped me debug this problem.

I've figured out the problem, when doing:

```
<li v-for="(filter, index) in filters"
     v-bind:key="index"
     v-on:click.self="addfilter(filter)">

    {{filter.name + new Date()}}

    <template v-if="filter.children">
        <filter-tree
         v-bind:filters="filter.children">
        </filter-tree>
    </template></div>

</li>
```

The `loop` on `li` creates a single parent with child multiple `filter-tree` components which is incorrect, it appears like a recursive call should be responsible to create/render itself & child components via the `v-for` on `filter-tree` as seen in official example.

Here's the **correct version** of my example: https://jsfiddle.net/z3sekaqy/

Answer (score 3):

The reason your `onUpdate` is called twice is because it is called once for the outer component, and once for your nested component.  I added a unique ID to each component instance and confirmed this in the alert.

The project you reference only changes state in the clicked component node because the entire tree is already rendered by using the `v-show` directive instead of a `v-if` directive.

You example actually adds nodes to the data, so the child component is rendered, and the outer component is updated.

Comment: But even if I just continue to add new childs to the same existing parent, why does it continue to trigger twice, I tried replace v-show with v-if as well & the same happens

Comment: Edit the question with some more findings, seem all children are being re-rendered for my example

Comment: It triggers once for the child you add, because the child did not yet exist in the virtual DOM.  Then when it is inserted into the parent, the parent triggers.  This is normal, and very different from the reference example, because in that case the data model is not mutated, and the nodes are pre rendered using `v-show`.

Comment: It adds an id to the component and shows it in the alert.

Comment: can you please save your changes? as it show's me the same fiddle as posted in the question

Comment: Sorry, the URL was missing the revision.  https://jsfiddle.net/spungin/4yruLegt/10/.  It works as expected, always 2 calls, one to the parent, and one to the inserted node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192313/discussion-between-akash-and-steven-spungin).

Comment: I'm wondering why does the id remain the same for multiple components, eg: jsfiddle.net/qxsdj3v7
shouldn't these increment for every instance of the component?